# none of my html5 styles are showing in old browsers like IE 6 and 7

Tags: html

I have made my site in html5 and added the following to the head section:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for some reason when I view my site in IE 6, 7 and early versions of mozilla and safari it only displays the html and the style sheet is not being accessed (there are no styles applied). I don't know what to do, someone please help!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the problematic site?

Comment: Hey Michael, those `script` tags look to be correct (depending on your directory structure), so we'll probably need to see more (a link to the page itself, more of your HTML) to debug a bit further.

Comment: Could you give a link to your site (you also can use http://jsfiddle.net) or more html code. I think we have to take look on your code.

Comment: Sorry, @michael did post a link to the site, in a comment to my answer (now deleted) .. it was http://www.michaelstephanwebdesigner.com/

Comment: You don't need to use both html5shiv and Modernizr.  See http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie.  Does removing html5shiv change things?

Answer (score 0):

IE6 barely supports HTML4, never mind HTML 5 :P Seriously though. IE6 is 10 years old, it's never going to properly support HTML5. You may find a JavaScript based workaround but it'll be flakey. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29

Comment: Including HTML5Shiv magically allows older versions of IE to recognize HTML5 tags. They should definitely be recognized, parsed, and displayed if that script is indeed running.

Comment: I have moved the shiv above my style sheet links but its still not rendering in older browsers any other ideas?

Comment: @michael I don't know if you caught my comment before I deleted my previous answer, but I was wrong, according to the `html5shiv` page, the order of including shouldn't matter. I've posted a new answer that might be it, other than that I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem is your slightly complicated `media` attribute.

Quoting [here](http://www.usabledevelopment.com/cssmedia),

> Since legacy browsers (e.g., Netscape
>   4.x) only support screen, you can hide all CSS from them by adding a
>   non-supported media type such as:
>   screen, projection or simply all

Maybe IE6, 7 and the others don't have full support either and so just fail to load the CSS.

Comment: I'd start by just removing the `media` attribute to see if it's actually the problem first. No point coming up with a solution if it's not the problem. I've not come across this before but I'm having a look around.

Comment: I guess the quickest solution would be to include the css with the media attribute in another IE conditional, and include it without if the conditional fails. You may not get exactly the result you're after and may have to tweak the css a bit though. I guess how far you go depends on how important the older browsers are to you.

Comment: thanks, removing the media queries does make a difference, so yeah conditional statement around an alternative stylesheet for IE. still doesn't fix problem with firefox 3.5, and safari 4 :( I wasn't too concerned about the older browsers until today someone was looking at my site with what must have been ie 6/7/8 and said it wasn't working. so annoying as my site is all over the place now in these browsers,lots of work to do :(

Comment: @michael Glad to hear that it helped but, as you say, probably a fair bit of work to do yet. I found this (http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/), hopefully it may ease things slightly!